# flow throws errors with a new react-native init project

Tags: react-native, flowtype

Getting ERRORS after running flow with a new react-native-init project.

Type of error: "Cant resolve module.."
[screenshot from the console  after running "yarn run flow"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIdPv.png)

Can someone please suggest what version of react-native /flow to use, so i can get rid of all these errors?

Thanks!

Comment: When you go to the doctor, do you just tell him you have a pain but not tell him where the pain is? Add the errors you are getting.

Comment: i have 1000 errors, all of them are coming from node_modules folder

Comment: Attached the link to the screenshot.

Answer (score 3):

- Hey , remove this project and then use my line react-native init
  Sampler. Go to that folder, cd Sampler. Run the command to start
  package, make sure you started the emulator  npm install && react
  native link &&  react-native run-android